# Try to write location in a text file

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager

I am developing for jailbreak iPhones. I am reading Beginning iOS 5 book. Currently, I have used a location code from the book and changed it slightly. The change which I have made in the code is that I am writing the location in a text file. But the program crashes. Although the same program without any modification is working perfectly.

Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 2.0f;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}






- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    FILE *file = fopen("/usr/locations.txt", "a");

    if (!file)
    {
        fprintf(file, "Error opening file");
    }

    if (startingPoint == nil)
        self.startingPoint = newLocation;

    NSString *latitudeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g\u00B0",
                                newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    latitudeLabel.text = latitudeString;


    NSNumber *latitude = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    NSNumber *longitude = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:newLocation.coordinate.longitude];


    NSString *longitudeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g\u00B0",
                                 newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    longitudeLabel.text = longitudeString;


    NSString *horizontalAccuracyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%gm",
                                          newLocation.horizontalAccuracy];
    horizontalAccuracyLabel.text = horizontalAccuracyString;


    NSString *altitudeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%gm",
                                newLocation.altitude];
    altitudeLabel.text = altitudeString;

    NSString *verticalAccuracyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%gm",
                                        newLocation.verticalAccuracy];
    verticalAccuracyLabel.text = verticalAccuracyString;


    CLLocationDistance distance = [newLocation
                                   distanceFromLocation:startingPoint];
    NSString *distanceString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%gm", distance];
    distanceTraveledLabel.text = distanceString;


    struct tm *local;
    time_t t;

    t = time(NULL);
    local = localtime(&t);

    fprintf(file, "Local time and Date: %s ", asctime(local));

    //----------------- ------------------------------------------------------------

    fprintf(file, "Latitude = %lf, Longitude = %lf \n", 
            newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);


    fclose(file);

}
```

Comment: Have you read [Apple’s documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/Introduction/Introduction.html) on file system access? Read that.

Comment: Now, I only want to print location on console. But I have not been able to do so as well. My development IDE is Xcode 4.2 and iOS version is 5.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Your most recent comment on the question says you want to print to the console instead. In order to print on the console you use `NSLog()`. When you use the format specifier for an object `%@`, the string substituted for the object is the object’s `description` method.

To print the location on the console use

```
NSLog(@"New location: %@", newLocation);
NSLog(@"Old location: %@", oldLocation);
```

The description method on [`CLLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007126-CH3-SW16) returns “A string of the form ‘latitude, longitude +/- accuracy m (speed kph / heading) @ date-time’.”